# Matplotlib, what to plot in a loop with user input

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is the first time i ask a question in here, so i hope i can ask it correctly any feedback on clarity is also appriciated.

I am forced to use matplotlib's plot function in the code i am currently writing, due to the datastructure i am working with. But it does not do well with plotting in loops. What i aim to do, with my plot, is to be able to modify a background window determined by the user, and either accept or reject the output. But as i understand there is some conflict between matplotlibs interactive function and the use of a loop. I am relativly new to python, so the code might not be the prittiest, but useually i gets the job done.
I am however at a complete loss for the particular problem. I have seen similair problems on the internet, which have been solved with plt.pause('timeinterval') but this is not an option in my case. or atleast i cannot see how i can use it, since i want to wait for user input. I have also tried plt.waitforbuttonpress() but this is not very intuetive, i cannot choose which button it should wait for.

I guess a third option is to extract the data from the format hyperspy uses and then make a canvas of my own, which forfills my needs, but this is very tidious for me, due to my lack of experience.

Do anyone have any alternative ways of producing a plot, preferably with matplotlib such that i can achive what i am trying?

By the way, i have also tried turning off interactive mode, and this does not do the trick unfurtunatly.

Some information  about the specs: This is running on a windows pc, using jupyterlab and python 3.10

I hope my dilemma is clear.

```
def set_background(self):
    """
    This function is ment to let the user define the background of each element, and then save the background for later use
    if working with multiple images of particles with the same composition.
    This function could be expanded to have interactive features so background would be clickable.
    """
    
    
    self.Background_tree = {}
    elements_in_sample = deepcopy(self.Data.metadata.Sample['elements'])
    Xray_in_sample = self.weighted_Xray_line_list
    data_sample = deepcopy(self.Data)
    integration_window = 1.3
    for element in elements_in_sample:
        data_sample.set_elements(elements=[element])
        for xray_line in (self.Data.metadata.Sample["xray_lines"]):
            if element in xray_line:   
                data_sample.set_lines([xray_line])
                background_points = input('please input the background points seperated by a space').split(' ')
                background_window = list(map(float,background_points))
                bw = data_sample.estimate_background_windows(background_window)
                iw = data_sample.estimate_integration_windows(integration_window)
                data_sample.sum().plot(True,bakcground_windows=background_window)
                happy = input('are you happy with the result?')
                if happy == 'y':
                #self.Data.get_lines_intensity(xray_lines=[xray_line], background_windows=bw, integration_windows=iw)
                    self.Background_tree[element+"_"+xray_line] = bw
```

Comment: did you check ``ipywidgets``?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
It does not seem like it can satisfy what i am looking for. The problem is that matplotlib's plot function crashes, when used in a loop, so i cannot have the user work with inputs, and see individual backgrounds added. I am forced to use matplotlib's plot function due to hyperspy(The module i am working with) integration of matplotlib.

Comment: ``ipywidgets`` will crash with ``input``, but will work just fine with ``labels`` (which is basically almost the same). And the plotting part will still need to be done using ``matplotlib``. I'll post an answer using ``ipywidgets`` to give you more insight at how it would look like. I'll delete it later if it doesn't satisfy you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as wg
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib widget

a = np.arange(50)
b = np.random.rand(50) + a
c = np.sin(a)
d = np.cos(b)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a,
                   'b': b,
                   'c': c,
                   'd': d})

userinput1 = wg.Text(value="", placeholder='Type something', description='x axis')
userinput2 = wg.Text(value="", placeholder='Type something', description='y axis')
buttonplot = wg.Button(description='Plot', disabled=False, button_style='', tooltip='Click me',icon='check')
buttonout = wg.Output()
display(HBox((userinput1, userinput2, buttonplot)))
display(buttonout)
plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def on_click_event(change):
    with buttonout:
        x = (userinput1.value)
        y = (userinput2.value)
        ax.plot(df[x], df[y], label=f'{y}')
        ax.legend()
buttonplot.on_click(on_click_event)
```

Output:

[image]

After user input and clicking the button:

[image]

More user input:

[image]

Does it satisfy your need or am I getting further away from your initial question?

Comment: I think something along those lines, is exactly what i need. 
It can be difficult to see if it will work at first glance, since i am using some methodes from a rather large module (Hyperspy) already, but it looks like it can be done, this way.
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Glad to help. I forgot to add the imports. Now it's added. Basically ``ipywidgets`` is not slow. ``matplotlib`` by itself is already slow, it doesn't get worse by adding ``ipywidgets``.